# Как выбрать элемент в словаре Python?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Код должен брать количество букв (colvo) и определять язык.
Мне нужно, чтобы colvo сопоставлялось с числом в словаре (alphabets).
А он сопоставляется не с числом, а с прикрепленным словом. Как решить?

```
alphabet = [0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']                                 # алфавит
colvo = len(alphabet) - 1                                                    # количество букв

alphabets = {6: 'итальянский', 26: 'английский', 33: 'русский'}              # список языков

if colvo == alphabets[6]:                                                   # вот тут проблема
    print(alphabets[6])
```

Comment: посмотрите на такую штуку https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/ определяет 55 языков

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
if alphabets.get(colvo):
    print(alphabets[colvo])
```